my app freeze and close when printing via Bluetooth
I am developing a Flutter application that generates PDFs for printing invoices and similar documents. I am using the following packages:
pdf: For creating PDF documents that support Arabic text.
image: For converting PDFs to images, which are then printed.
flutter_esc_pos_utils: For handling thermal printing but it lacks Arabic support.
print_bluetooth_thermal: For connecting to a Bluetooth thermal printer.
Problem:
Since flutter_esc_pos_utils doesn't support Arabic characters, I opted for the PDF-to-image approach. The idea is to create the PDF using the pdf package and then convert it into an image using the image package. This image is then printed using the blue_thermal_printer package.
However, when handling larger documents or images, the application crashes and unexpectedly closes. I suspect it is due to memory consumption since converting PDFs to high-resolution images can be resource-intensive, especially for large documents.
Question:
How can I optimize the memory usage or prevent the app from crashing when generating large PDFs or handling multiple pages? Are there any alternative approaches or strategies to achieve the following requirements:
Printing documents in a thermal printer.
Supporting Arabic characters.
Using Bluetooth thermal printers effectively.
Any guidance or suggestions on optimizing PDF generation, image handling, or dealing with large memory usage in Flutter would be greatly appreciated.
code:
class BluetoothThermalPrinter extends ThermalPrinterBlue {
  BluetoothThermalPrinter._();

  static BluetoothThermalPrinter? _instance;

  factory BluetoothThermalPrinter.instance() {
    _instance ??= BluetoothThermalPrinter._();
    return _instance!;
  }

  BluetoothInfo? _device;
  BluetoothInfo? _Olddevice;
  CapabilityProfile? _profile;
  Generator? _generator;
  List<int> _bytes = [];

  BluetoothInfo? get device {
    if (_device == null) {
      final deviceName = sharedPreferences.getString('deviceName');
      final deviceMac = sharedPreferences.getString('deviceMac');

      if (!deviceMac.isEmptyOrNull && !deviceMac.isEmptyOrNull) {
        _device ??= BluetoothInfo(name: deviceName!, macAdress: deviceMac!);
      }
    }
    return _device;
  }

  Future<bool> isPermissionGranted() async {
    return PrintBluetoothThermal.isPermissionBluetoothGranted;
  }

  BluetoothInfo? contain(List<BluetoothInfo> list) {
    return list.firstWhere(
      (element) => element.macAdress == _device?.macAdress,
    );
  }

  Future<PermissionStatus> getPermission() async {
    final status = await Permission.bluetooth.request();
    print(status);
    return Permission.bluetooth.status;
  }

  /// error code 001: _profile is null
  CapabilityProfile? get profile => _profile;

  Generator? get generator => _generator;

  List<int> get bytes => _bytes;

  void setDevice(BluetoothInfo? device) {
    _device = device;
    _Olddevice ??= device;
  }

  Future<void> _setProfile() async {
    _profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();
  }

  Future<void> _setGenerator(PaperSize paperSize) async {
    await _setProfile();
    if (_profile == null) {
      throw const PrintException(
          message: 'there is error please try again 001');
    }
    _generator = Generator(paperSize, _profile!);
  }

  void printFrom(String imgPath, PaperSize paperSize) async {
    final file = File(imgPath);
    if (!await file.exists()) {
      throw const PrintException(message: 'Invoice is missing');
    }
    await _setGenerator(paperSize);
    final imageBytesUint8List = await file.readAsBytes();
    Image image = decodeJpg(imageBytesUint8List)!;
    _bytes = [];
    _bytes += generator!.image(image);

    final lists = splitBytesAtNewline(_bytes);
    // Define the sequence to remove
    // Remove all instances of the sequence
    for (int i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
      await PrintBluetoothThermal.writeBytes(lists[i]).then(
        (value) async {
          if (value && i == lists.length - 1) {
            await PrintBluetoothThermal.writeBytes(
                generator!.cut(mode: PosCutMode.full));
          }
        },
      );
    }
  }

  List<List<int>> splitBytesAtNewline(List<int> bytes) {
    List<List<int>> chunks = [];
    List<int> currentChunk = [];
    int num = 0;
    for (int byte in bytes) {
      currentChunk.add(byte);
      if (byte == 10) {
        num++;
        // ASCII code for newline '\n'
        if(num == 10){
          chunks.add(currentChunk);
          currentChunk = [];
        }

      }
    }

    // Add any remaining bytes as the last chunk
    if (currentChunk.isNotEmpty) {
      chunks.add(currentChunk);
    }

    return chunks;
  }

  Future<List<BluetoothInfo>> getBluetoothDevices() async {
    return PrintBluetoothThermal.pairedBluetooths;
  }

  Future<bool> connectTo() async {
    if (_device == null) {
      throw const PrintException(
          message:
              'there is no paired device,please pair with bluetooth printer ');
    } else {
      final connect = await PrintBluetoothThermal.connect(
          macPrinterAddress: _device!.macAdress);
      if (connect && _device!.name != _Olddevice?.name) {
        sharedPreferences.setString('deviceName', _device!.name);
        sharedPreferences.setString('deviceMac', _device!.macAdress);
      }

      return connect;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> isConnect() {
    return PrintBluetoothThermal.connectionStatus;
  }

  Future<bool> disconnect() {
    return PrintBluetoothThermal.disconnect;
  }
}

Packages in Use:
pdf: To create PDF documents.
image: To convert PDFs into images.
flutter_esc_pos_utils: For handling printing tasks.
print_bluetooth_thermal: For Bluetooth printing.
To tackle this, I attempted to split the image data into chunks and send these chunks separately. My approach is to split the image data into chunks of 10 lines each using the ASCII newline character 10 as a delimiter. This way, I can send smaller pieces of data to the printer efficiently.
This code for handling the split part:
List<List<int>> splitBytesAtNewline(List<int> bytes) {
    List<List<int>> chunks = [];
    List<int> currentChunk = [];
    int num = 0;
    for (int byte in bytes) {
      currentChunk.add(byte);
      if (byte == 10) {
        num++;
        // ASCII code for newline '\n'
        if(num == 10){
          chunks.add(currentChunk);
          currentChunk = [];
          num = 0;
        }

      }
    }

    // Add any remaining bytes as the last chunk
    if (currentChunk.isNotEmpty) {
      chunks.add(currentChunk);
    }

    return chunks;
  }

That the part for sending data to printer:
  void printFrom(String imgPath, PaperSize paperSize) async {
    final file = File(imgPath);
    if (!await file.exists()) {
      throw const PrintException(message: 'Invoice is missing');
    }
    await _setGenerator(paperSize);
    final imageBytesUint8List = await file.readAsBytes();
    Image image = decodeJpg(imageBytesUint8List)!;
    _bytes = [];
    _bytes += generator!.image(image);

    final lists = splitBytesAtNewline(_bytes);
    // Define the sequence to remove
    // Remove all instances of the sequence
    for (int i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
      await PrintBluetoothThermal.writeBytes(lists[i]).then(
        (value) async {
          if (value && i == lists.length - 1) {
            await PrintBluetoothThermal.writeBytes(
                generator!.cut(mode: PosCutMode.full));
          }
        },
      );
    }
  }

While this approach works better than sending the entire image at once, it’s still not as efficient as needed. The printing speed is slow, and memory usage can still be high. I suspect that splitting by newlines might not be the optimal method for large documents or images.
So is there a more efficient way to split or process image data to reduce memory usage and improve printing speed?
Are there any other strategies or best practices for handling large image data in thermal printing?
Could changing how the data is chunked improve the performance, or is there a better method for splitting image data?
Any help or insights on optimizing this approach for thermal printers in Flutter would be greatly appreciated..
